Access port for tagged VLAN just doesn't work for vlan aware bridge
I am on my whits end. I have a config which identically works on a different machine (different board, CPU, network adapter though):
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual
    
auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet manual
        bridge-ports eno1
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        bridge-vlan-aware yes
        bridge-vids 1-4096
        bridge-pvid 1

auto vmbr0.1
iface vmbr0.1 inet static
        address 10.227.1.21/24
        gateway 10.227.1.254

iface vmbr0.4 inet static
        address 10.227.4.67/24

Network interface eno1 is connected to a managed switch with trunk access port, VLAN4 tagged and VLAN1 untagged. In above configuration, vmbr0.1 works and vmbr0.4 does not work: I cannot reach any other host on the same VALN4. If I run tcpdump on vmbr0.4, I can only see ARP requests being sent out but nothing received.
Now, on this, I could expect all VLANs so something seems wrong:
# bridge vlan show
port              vlan-id  
eno1              1 PVID Egress Untagged
vmbr0             1
                  4

The exact identical config works on another PC with the same managed switch port (but using enp3s0 and enp4s0 as bridge-ports instead).
VLAN per se are working: If I remove the VLAN aware bridge but instead configure eno1.1 and eno1.4, everything works as expected too!
In case it matters, it's a I219-LM network adapter in a HP Elitedesk 800 G mini PC. It uses e1000e driver.
What the heck can possibly be wrong here?

I found the answer: I specified 1-4096. This is out of bounds and it’s silently being ignored. Hence only VID 1 is actually assigned.
Specifying vlan-vids 1-4094 works (which was a typo when I moved the config from one host to the other).
